# How can I select the first quote ("), disconsider the between content, and select the second quote ("), given a pattern?

Tags: regex

"234";"CASA "C"";"AM";

"235";"CASA F";"AM";

"236";"CASA "A"";"AM";

I have a file with several lines like the ones above. And I would like to select only the firt quote ("), disconsider the between content, and finally select the other quote ("). So that I could turn

this: "CASA "C"";
into this: "CASA C".

For these cases, I already have a pattern that matches the full content:

```
(\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\")
```

Searching I found a way to match one of the quotes, but I couldn't "merge" the two matches of the quote:

```
((?=(\"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\"\")).)
```

That is what I got so far! Thanks!

--

I am using Sublime Text.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you mean by "*desconsider*"?

Comment: are you looking for a regex find and replace sort of solution?

Comment: I've corrected, @Bergi, thanks! Disconsider I mean, ignore the middle content!

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath, actually just find because, if it matches, I will just delete the unwanted quotes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sth. like `"([^"]+)"([^"]+)""`

See this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQvjuf/3) here

Comment: No need to escape the quotes. And I guess you meant `[^"]` not `[^;]`?

Comment: Hi @Andie2302, thanks! At the demo, it matches the full ocurrence! But what I am trying to reach, if it is possible, is that at a single click on "Find All", based on the pattern, only selects two quotes, and ignore the middle content!

Comment: @DanielsonAlvesJúnior That might be possible with lookahead and lookbehind, but would get really complicated. Instead, just use a pattern replace: `"$1$2"`.

Comment: @Bergi, how i put these two at the pattern given by Andie? /([^"]+)"([^"]+)/

Comment: @DanielsonAlvesJúnior You use the one in the search field and the other in the replacement field. See http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#using-regular-expressions-in-sublime-text

Comment: Yes, @Bergi, the demo of Andie replaces correctly! But I am applying on Sublime, and it's duplicating! But the answer is there, I will just adapt! Thanks, guys!

Comment: @Bergi, on Sublime, I had to put the rest of the pattern, because it was matching other cases at the rest of the line _(there are 62 columns for 100k lines!)_. So I added the rest of the pattern **/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/** to the Andie's solution, and on Sublime, I put only **$2** and it worked!